# Linear regression and exponential distribution

Tags: regression, distributions, normal-distribution, linear, exponential-distribution

I'm running a simple ordinal least squares regression. My dependent variable is normally distributed, while my independent is exponentially distributed. Will this be a problem and, if yes, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: ¿Is the dependent variable a count? ¿Can you transform the dependent variable?

Comment: Yes the dependent variable is just a scale variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. In linear regression there are no assumptions about the independent variables. (I prefer to call them "regressors" or "covariates" because they are usually dependent on things). We take the regressor(s) as fixed, given, or known, so we don't care (too much) about their distribution. The skewed values will produce high *leverage* observations.